# Windows Shared folders vs Samba

Tags: windows, networking, samba, shared-folders

What is the difference between Windows shared folder mechanism and samba (cifs)? Are they completely different things?

I have a problem with my apltituter (Onkyo TX-NR646). It is able to work with shared folders to play music from the network. It works fine when I share something from Windows 7.
I wanted to buy some network disk to play music without my PC on. I've chosen welland me-740AN. It has FTP and SAMBA access to files. Unfortunately it doesn't work with my amplituner (connection from my PC to this drive is ok). Maybe Onkyo doesn't support Samba access? How can I check it?
http://www.onkyo.com/manual/txnr646/adv/en/index.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Through web UI for welland me-740AN  try to set anonymous authorisation. I think problem here, because your Onkyo TX-NR646 cannot play music from shares with password protection.